# Porque en mi input value se generan espacios en blanco

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control txt_respuesta54_act" name="txt_respuesta54_act" required value="
<?php
  if ($trim == 1){echo trim($respuesta_Trans_Q2);}
  elseif ($trim == 2){echo $respuesta_Trans_Q3;}
  elseif ($trim == 3){echo $respuesta_Trans_Q4;}
  elseif ($trim == 4){echo $respuesta_Trans_Q1;}
?>">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código lo que hace es recuperar desde la BD valores dependiendo del valor actual de $trim, el problema surge en los espacios en blanco que antepone en los input, el resultado de la imagen es la forma en la cual me los muestra.

Comment: ¿Seguro que son espacios en blanco? ¿Cuál es la salida de var_dump(trim($respuesta_Trans_Q2));

Comment: Yo creo que es en el css... el ancho o algun padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te convendría guardar en una variable y luego hacerle un echo a esa variable? Incluso te resultaría mejor trabajar con un switch (ya que será un poco mas ordenado)

```
<?php
  switch ($trim) {
     case(1): $rpta = trim($respuesta_Trans_Q2); break;
     case(2): $rpta = $respuesta_Trans_Q3); break;
     case(3): $rpta = $respuesta_Trans_Q4); break;
     case(4): $rpta = $respuesta_Trans_Q1); break;
     default: $rpta = "no recuperado... mensaje default"; break;
  }
?>


<input type="text" class="form-control txt_respuesta54_act" name="txt_respuesta54_act" required value="<? echo $rpta; ?">
```

Por cierto, podrías pasarnos que tipos de datos estas manejando/queriendo imprimir? De forma que podamos tratar de repetir el problema que se presenta y asi darte una respuesta?

Por cierto (x2), porque el == 1 tiene un trim() y los otros no?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú aporte me fue de mucha utilidad enserio muchas gracias.

Comment: y eso del trim lo tenia el primero por cuestiones de prueba, pero gracias a ti pude solventar mi error.